# Remote command output to text file (remote system)

Tags: powershell

I know I must be using these commands wrong but I can't seem to find a solution. I believe the issue is with my use of the invoke-command and out-file. I'm trying to check to see if a process is running on multiple remote machines and write their states back to a text file on the host system. Even if it wrote to the remote system I could work with that but I cant seem to get anything.

```
$MyDomain=’mydomain’
$MyClearTextUsername=’myusername’ 
$MyClearTextPassword=’mypassword’
$MyUsernameDomain=$MyDomain+’\’+$MyClearTextUsername
$SecurePassword=Convertto-SecureString –String $MyClearTextPassword 
    -AsPlainText –force
$MyCredentials=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
$MyUsernameDomain,$SecurePassword
$Servers = ( "server1","server2","server3")

$output = foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $MyCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock 
{
    Get-Service -Name service | select name, status, PSComputername, Runspaceid 
} | Out-File -filepath 'c:\TEMP\check.txt'
}
Write-output $output | Out-File -filepath 'c:\TEMP\check.txt'
```

edit: I don't believe the last line is needed but I threw it in just to see if I could get anything out.

Comment: You could try `$var = Invoke-Command ... { }; $var | Out-File x.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not capturing anything in `$output` because you are redirecting all of the output from your `Invoke-Command` to `Out-File -filepath 'c:\TEMP\check.txt'`. `Get-Service` doesn't return that much data, especially once's it's been deserialized when it returns from the remote session, so I wouldn't bother with the `Select` statement. Even if you do want to include the `Select` statement you are specifying `PSComputerName` which doesn't get added until the data comes back from the remote system, so you may want to move that `Select` to outside of the scriptblock and after the `Invoke-Command` in the pipeline. Plus, since you are outputting with `Out-File` your local file is being overwritten each time that call is made, so the first server's results are saved, then overwritten by the second server's results, then by the third server's results. After that, since `$output` has nothing (as all output was redirected to file), you are outputting an empty variable to the same file, effectively erasing the service state of the third server.

But this really all becomes a moot point if the script is run with the credentials that has access to the remote servers. You can specify one or more computer names to the `Get-Service` cmdlet, so this could become as simple as:

```
$Results = Get-Service Service -ComputerName 'Server1','Server2','Server3'
$Results | Select name, status, PSComputername, Runspaceid | Set-Content 'C:\TEMP\check.txt'
```

Just to make sure... you are looking for a service right? Not just a process? Because if it isn't a service you would need to use `Get-Process` instead of `Get-Service`.

If you want to output the data to the remote server you could do:

```
$output = foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential $MyCredentials
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock 
{
    Get-Service -Name service | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\Temp\ServiceState.txt
} | select name, status, PSComputername, Runspaceid 
}
$output | Out-File -filepath 'c:\TEMP\check.txt'
```

That should make a file in the C:\Temp folder on each server with the state of the service, as well as pass the information back to the local host, where it is passed to `Select` and stored in `$output`. At the end I output `$output` to file, just as you did.

I guess in the end you could just remove the `Out-File` call from within your loop, and it would probably do what you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that, I'm still a novice when it comes to powershell.